# Is there a way to do a conditional check against whether your code is obfuscated in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, obfuscation

Is there a way to check whether your code base is obfuscated programmatically?

In my project, I'm using reflection to load classes from an outside DLL (which I control). The data for loading the information (assembly and class name) are stored in a resource file.

Once I obfuscate the project, I am unable to link the outside DLL into the output EXE (i.e. roll up all assemblies into a single output executable), because the assembly name in the resource file is no longer correct (the DLL has become part of the EXE). But I have to preserve the un-obfuscated functionality as well for debugging purposes.

What I'd *like* to do, is have the code check to see if it has been obfuscated at runtime. If it hasn't, use the assembly name in the resource file; if it has, use the name of the application. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Obfuscators, such as Dotfuscate, will put an assembly level Custom Attribute on the assembly. If that is the case of your obfuscator, check to see if the attribute is present, such as:

```
bool foundObfuscatationAttribute = false;
foreach (object attribute in attributes)
{
    if (attribute.GetType().FullName == "DotfuscatorAttribute")
    {
        foundObfuscatationAttribute = true;
        break;
    }
}
//If found...
```

Since we don't want to reference the assembly that contains the attribute itself, we check by name.

Comment: I've tried this out, and it works perfectly. We're currently using Dotfuscator, so your code-snippet was spot-on (I did, however, confirm the attribute's existence using .NET Reflector, just in case). The only down-shot I see if that, if we switch to a different obfuscation tool, the code will break with no warning. But that's what good documentation is for, right? :)

Answer (score 3):

Ask for the type info of a class you know will be obfuscated and check if the name is still the unobfuscated one. In code `typeof(MyClass).Name == "MyClass"` (may need include the namespace).

Comment: I liked this answer, too. It's simple, and easy to use. I prefer the attribute check (above) because it won't break if the class-name changes. All the same, I'd set this as a second answer to the question if I could.

Comment: Note that as of C# 6.0, you can use the `nameof` operator for the right-hand side of that expression. The compiler converts the simple name of the type to a string literal. So the expression essentially says `nameOfMyClassAtRuntime == nameOfMyClassAtCompileTime`. Assuming the obfuscator itself operates on compiled assemblies, and it doesn't change the right-hand side (the answer I'm replying to makes these same assumptions), the expression will tell you if `MyClass` was renamed.

Comment: Using nameof breaks the check, at least in my implementation with .NET Framework 4.8. The problem is that the JIT compiler will change nameof(MyClass) == "MyClass" to just true, and so it will return true even if obfuscated. I even tried using the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)] attribute on my check method, but it doesn't seem to honor that. However using typeof does work, so if you're having trouble with nameof then perhaps go back to typeof.

Answer (score 0):

Set a compile flag or some kind of flag you can reach using Reflection to check if it is

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if the assembly(dll) is obfuscated from Dotfuscator, without need to the dependencies in the folder is:

```
public static bool IsDllOfuscated(string dirFile)
{
    return Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(dirFile)).GetType("DotfuscatorAttribute") != null;        
}
```